# what are the pitfalls in implementing Dynamics CRM integration using plugins?

Tags: plugins, synchronization, dynamics-crm, integration

We are trying to choose an approach we should follow in integrating on-promise Dynamic CRM with other companies and third-party software and systems, we use in our company.
Concerning this msdn page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932127.aspx we have some options. But my team members want to implement integration through service calls to external systems inside plugins.

I am talking about Data Integration and Data Synchronization for a total solution that Dynamics CRM is a part of it. Considering the limitations in plugin and the options written in the mentioned msdn page, I think bringing the integration code and logic out of the CRM stuffs and encapsulate it in into a separate connector solution would be a better solution. The connector of course 
should support real-time and offline or on-demand data synchronization.

I want to know what are the disadvantages/advantages in plugins approach in integration with external systems, and what are advantages/disadvantages of using a connector solution?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of integration are we talking about? Do you want real-time "enrichment" where, when a user opens a form or loads a grid, data from another system is retrieved and displayed on demand?  Would you be storing it after retrieval to keep a cache in CRM? Or do you guys plan to push data into CRM at some regular interval?

Comment: @Polshgiant, I have editted the post in order to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing integration to third party system within plugins can be a good approach.  You should be aware of how plugins work and how the result of your integration affects the success or failure of the database action that triggers the plugin.  Some important items to consider:

- Is the database action dependent upon a result from the integration. For instance if your integration is verifying/modifying your data, you may want the result of the integration to affect what is written to the database.  Such a plugin would probably be registered on a pre plugin.
- Should the database action go through if the integration fails?  Many integration are done in a post plugin outside of the transaction so that if the integration fails it does not cause the database action to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like something you might want to solve using tooling outside of CRM. For example Scribe, SSIS (with Kingswaysoft) or some ESB type application.

Especially the first two provide no-code solutions and would probably have a lower TCO than writing your own plugins.